# Vector Potential and Zero Divergence

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

In the following problem and many others in magnetostatics (Griffiths book) I'm asked to check that $\nabla . A = 0$. While "It is
always possible to make the vector potential divergenceless." also "we are at liberty to pick that as we see fit". I think I missed that the book was Imposing the Coulomb gauge condition.

If B is uniform, show that $A(r) = −1/2 (r × B)$ works.

Why do I have to check that $\nabla . A = 0$  ?

Couldn't  $\nabla . A$ be anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$ could be anything, but the relationship between $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ you show is only true in the Coulomb gauge.

It's straightforward to show that $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ by taking the curl of that equation. However, I can also write

$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r})) + \nabla \phi(\mathbf{r})$

for any scalar potential $\phi$, and $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ is still true, but $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}=0$ is not in general true.

I don't have that book, so I'm not sure if the phrasing in the question makes things confusing.

Comment: Thanks! The question says: "If $B$ is uniform, show that $A(r) = −1/
2 (r × B)$ works. That is, check
that $∇ · A = 0$ and $∇ × A = B$. Is this result unique, or are there other functions
with the same divergence and curl?" My problem was that when the vector potential is introduced I was hoping something like "From now on we will always need the Coulomb gauge condition.".

Comment: That does seem a little confusing. I think the point is to make you think about what makes the solution unique, and the Coulomb gauge is the simplest way to go about it. Maybe if they asked you to calculate $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$ instead of asking you to confirm that it is zero, it would make more sense.